# Pass variable from callback function in component to template

Tags: ember.js

I've uploaded a file with ember-cli-dropzone (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-dropzonejs). This works fine. Now i need to update my template with the filename.

Inside a component I have the filename in a callback function. But now i need to pass this to the routes setupController function. So i can use the controller.set, as shown below.

The component JS:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
   submit: function(){
     this.sendAction('action', this.submission);
   }
 },
 uploadSuccess: function(file, response) {
   if (response == '200') {
    return file.name;
   }
 }
});
```

setupController inside the route:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
    var submission = this.store.createRecord('submission', { filter: { assignment_id: model.id } });

    submission.filename = filenamePlease; 
    controller.set('submission', submission);

}
```

compenent inside template:

```
{{submission-form submission=submission user=user action='createSubmission'}}
```

component HBS:

```
<form {{action 'submit' on='submit'}}>
  {{drop-zone url='http://localhost:4200/api/uploads' success=uploadSuccess}}
  {{input type="hidden" value=submission.filename}}
  <button class="bnt" type="submit">{{buttonLabel}}</button>
</form>
```

How do i get the corresponding template to update after the file has uploaded and uploadSuccess has returned the filename?

Comment: `setupController` is executed once before route and template are completely setup. Components are rendered later. So, you would have to alter the past.

Comment: I've also tried to do submission.set('filename', file.name); inside the uploadSuccess function. I got submission undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In component JavaScript file:

```
uploadSuccess(file, response) {
    if (response == '200') {
        this.sendAction('uploadAction', file.name);
    }
}
```

Component declaration in template:

```
{{submission-form
    submission=submission
    user=user
    action='createSubmission'
    uploadAction='uploadSuccess'
}}
```

Action in **controller** (not in route):

```
actions: {
    uploadSuccess(name) {
        // you have got your filename as `name` here
        this.set('submission.filename', name);
    }
}
```

You said you have wrong context in `uploadSuccess`. You can try:

```
uploadSuccess: Ember.run(this, function(file, response) {
    if (response == '200') {
        this.sendAction('uploadAction', file.name);
    }
})
```

Comment: Your solution looks good to me, however: In the component file: this.sendAction('uploadAction', file.name); This is the dropzone object... So i get this.sendAction is not a function

Comment: Dropzone can't find the new uploadSuccess function. "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" That's the same error when you totally delete the uploadSuccess function.